# Tiling of genus 2 surface by 8 pentagons

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry

In theses [these notes](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~hjrw2/Notes/cubenotes.pdf), Example 5.6, it is said that there is a "symmetric tiling of a genus 2 surface by 8 right-angled hyperbolic pentagons".

Question 1: What does this tiling look like?

Question 2: Is it always possible to tile a genus $n$ surface by $f$ regular $n$-gons with interior angle $\pi/v$ (so that $v$ faces meet at every vertex) as long as the restriction given by the Euler characteristic 
$$\chi=2-2n= f-nf/2+nf/v$$
is satisfied?
Answering [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198040/regular-tiling-of-a-surface-of-genus-2-by-heptagons?r=searchresults), Igor Rivin says yes, but it seems his argument only shows that regular hyperbolic $n$-gons of interior angle smaller than the interior angle of a euclidean regular $n$-gon exist.

Comment: Q2 was answered at MSE two years ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380335/is-a-regular-tessellation-p-q-always-possible-on-some-closed-surface-s/2385525#2385525

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A picture answering Question 1 is here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/331408/1345

Question 2 is a duplicate of [regular tiling of a surface of genus 2 by heptagons](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198040/regular-tiling-of-a-surface-of-genus-2-by-heptagons), although as you point out the accepted answer there is unsatisfactory. I've given a link there answering this question.

Answer (score 6):

Ian answered the second question as asked, but in case you meant to ask a different question: there is not always a **symmetric** tiling by regular polygons of the given type, even if those restrictions hold. For instance, there is no tiling of the genus 2 surface by heptagons meeting 3 at a vertex so that the symmetries permute and rotate the heptagons in all possible ways. Said differently, the Hurwitz bound of $168(g-1)$ on the number of symmetries of a genus $g$ surface is not achieved for $g=2$.

Comment: As you're probably aware, Michael Larsen has addressed how frequently the Hurwitz bound is achieved. https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1882031 But one could also just ask for a transitive action on the faces (or on the vertices). Bestvina's example desribed by Christopher is of this type. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198040/regular-tiling-of-a-surface-of-genus-2-by-heptagons

Comment: Can you make a face-transitive tiling by heptagons in every genus? (Or various other regular polygons.)

Comment: Any surface is a cyclic cover of genus 2, so maybe a dihedral action?